# zend framework losing session

Tags: flash, zend-framework, session, upload

I am trying to implement a Flash uploader in my Zend framework application but I am having problems with the session.

The Flash does not send any cookie headers and this is why the session is lost. I am trying to send the sessionId as a post param and in my bootstrap file I added a session_id($_POST['session_id]) but this doenst seem to work.

I am using a MySQL table as session storage

I tryed to debug the error and as far as I see, the session_id is set, and the storage returns the corect data from the database but it doesn't seem to be set correctly in the $_SESSION global.

And even stranger it seems to work on my Windows computer but not on the Linux staging server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know if you are using Suhosin with your PHP installation?

I've heard a [few reports](http://swfupload.org/forum/generaldiscussion/1206) of Suhosin doing this to the sessions, solution in this case is to disable `suhosin.session.cryptua` in php.ini.

Anyway, if that's not your problem, just to be sure with the basics:

1. Make sure you pass your `session_id()` in a post from your Flash, for example, with [SWF Upload](http://swfupload.org/), this is done by passing it in the [`post_params`](http://demo.swfupload.org/Documentation/) value of the configuration array.
2. Make sure you call `session_id($_POST['session_id])` before `session_start()`

But anyway, it is probably related to your PHP installation if you are saying it works under your Windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to various bugs that have been reported over the years, though in most cases it worked on linux and not on windows.

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-2459
https://www.zend.com/en/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=16104&S=de7d9b854db445eb37d0f33470cac6b0

and as recently as last month:

http://blog.rac.me.uk/2009/01/09/php-zend-session-dont-set-it-up-in-the-initalizer/

-- MarkusQ

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your controller action:

```
session_write_close();
session_id($this->_getParam('PHPSESSID'));
session_start();
```